# Probability that device a) does not work if the system does not work? b) does not work if the system operates?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

The following circuit operates if and only if
there is a path of functional devices from left to right.
The probability that each device functions is as shown.
Assume that the probability that a device is functional
does not depend on whether or not other devices are
functional.

[image]

What is the probability that device A
a) does not work if the system does not work? 
b) does not work if the system operates?

So I have tried working on finding the $\mathbb{P}(A|S)$, wherein $\mathbb{P}(S)$ is the probability that the system will not work and $\mathbb{P}(A)$ is the probability that device A will not work. However, I just can't seem how to find $\mathbb{P}(A\cap S)$.
From what I computed, $\mathbb{P}(S)=0.070625$.
How can I find $\mathbb{P}(A\cap S)$?

Edit: there was a first problem about this one and by solving that I already knew what to do with P[S]. Btw, thank you for the edits people hehehe

Comment: It would help us help you if you edited into your question what you had tried and where you were getting stuck

Comment: okay, thank you @Henry. Gonna edit this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a result close to yours as of $P(S)$.

I calculated first

$$P(work)=0.9\cdot0.8\cdot0.7[1-0.95^3]+0.95^3[1-0.9\cdot0.8\cdot0.7]+0.9\cdot0.8\cdot0.7\cdot0.95^3=0.929258$$

Thus your $P(S)=0.070742$. Perhaps your calculation are ok but there is just a different approx.

Now to calcualte $P(\overline{A} \cap S)=0.1\cdot[1-0.95^3]=0.0142625$

(if A doesn't work, in order to have the system out of work it is necessary that the lower branch of the system doesn't work too)

Thus $P(\overline{A}|S)\approx 20.16\%$

Similar arguments for the other request

EDIT: the easiest way to calculate $P(S)=[1-0.9\cdot0.8\cdot0.7][1-0.95^3]=0.070742$...I did a lot of useless calculations... :(

Comment: thank you, twas a great help. thank you for the enlightenment hehehe

Comment: @keplerxx : I made an edit to simplify the calculations...

Comment: It's okay, it's just that there are other ways to find P[S]